# Creators are not showing on Explorer

Tags: solana-program, rust, metadata

I sign the pda account in a creators array but it is not showing on explorer. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the mint address so that i can check as well if its showing or not

Comment: and since you are making the verified as true are you making the PDA sign that transaction ?